# Returning instantiated class in php...BigBluebutton

Tags: php, json, bigbluebutton

I am new to PHP and trying to a third party code namely Big blue button api 
https://github.com/bigbluebutton/bigbluebutton/tree/master/labs/bbb-api-php

I try to call `BigBlueButton->createMeeting()` function which looks like this :

```
public function createMeeting($createMeetingParams, $xml = '')
{
    $xml = $this->processXmlResponse($this
        ->getCreateMeetingURL($createMeetingParams), $xml);
    //$xml is fine
    return new CreateMeetingResponse($xml);
}
```

CreateMeetingResponse class

```
  namespace BigBlueButton\Responses;

/**
 * Class CreateMeetingResponse
 * @package BigBlueButton\Responses
 */
class CreateMeetingResponse extends BaseResponse
{
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getMeetingId()
    {
        return $this->rawXml->meetingID->__toString();
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAttendeePassword()
    {
        return $this->rawXml->attendeePW->__toString();
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getModeratorPassword()
    {
        return $this->rawXml->moderatorPW->__toString();
    }

    /**
     * Creation timestamp.
     *
     * @return double
     */
    public function getCreationTime()
    {
        return doubleval($this->rawXml->createTime);
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getVoiceBridge()
    {
        return intval($this->rawXml->voiceBridge);
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDialNumber()
    {
        return $this->rawXml->dialNumber->__toString();
    }

    /**
     * Creation date at the format "Sun Jan 17 18:20:07 EST 2016".
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCreationDate()
    {
        return $this->rawXml->createDate->__toString();
    }

    /**
     * @return true
     */
    public function hasUserJoined()
    {
        return $this->rawXml->hasUserJoined->__toString() == 'true';
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getDuration()
    {
        return intval($this->rawXml->duration);
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function hasBeenForciblyEnded()
    {
        return $this->rawXml->hasBeenForciblyEnded->__toString() == 'true';
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getMessageKey()
    {
        return $this->rawXml->messageKey->__toString();
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getMessage()
    {
        $this->rawXml->message->__toString();
    }
}
```

BaseResponse class

```
namespace BigBlueButton\Parameters;

/**
 * Class BaseParameters.
 */
abstract class BaseParameters
{
    /**
     * @param $array
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function buildHTTPQuery($array)
    {
        return http_build_query(array_filter($array));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    abstract public function getHTTPQuery();
}
```

Now when I do call the `BigBlueButton->createMeeting()` function, I am expecting an object which I can encode to json ,But what I get is this (I have used `print_r()` here..):

```
BigBlueButton\Responses\CreateMeetingResponse Object
(
    [rawXml:protected] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [returncode] => FAILED
            [messageKey] => idNotUnique
            [message] => A meeting already exists with that meeting ID.  Please use a different meeting ID.
        )

)
```

I am not sure what is happening but I think the prefixed namespace '`BigBlueButton\Responses\CreateMeetingResponse Object`' is the problem. I want to parse the response I get to an json object in php but cannot

Here is where I try to parse it

```
function easymeet_create_meeting($id) {
  // Create BBB object
  $bbb = new BigBlueButton\BigBlueButton();

  //creating meeting parameter
  $meetingParas=new BigBlueButton\Parameters\CreateMeetingParameters('123456','sned');

  //Creatign meeting
  return json_encode($bbb->createMeeting($meetingParas)); 
   ///print_r($bbb->createMeeting($meetingParas)) give the xml response shown above

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return part looks right. The error you are getting is coming from `BigBlueButton->createMeeting()`

You already have created a meeting with the ID you used. Are you generating a new Meeting ID to pass in with the XML when you create a new meeting?

Edit:

To be able to json_encode the response you will need to use the `getRawXml()` function since `$rawXml` is a protected property of the base class and the rest of the class is just methods. So:

```
public function createMeeting($createMeetingParams, $xml = '')
{
    $xml = $this->processXmlResponse($this
        ->getCreateMeetingURL($createMeetingParams), $xml);
    //$xml is fine
    $resp = new CreateMeetingResponse($xml);
    return $resp->getRawXml();
}
```

Should return just the `SimpleXMLElement` which you can then json_encode.

Comment: I am not talking about the error, I know that is the response I should be getting but I can't parse the response in json so I can use in my application

Comment: Ok, gotcha, can you add the code where you are trying to json_encode the response?

Comment: I have added the calling function

Comment: I think I understand the issue now, I edited the answer accordingly.